# Ifelse statement with factors in R

Tags: r

I have data similar to this:

```
X             Y
45            45
56            34
Unspecified   Unspecified
Unspecified   23
```

I wanted to use an ifelse statement to compare these - giving a 1 if column X is not equal to column Y, and a 0 otherwise. I have been attempting something like this:

```
ifelse(data$X == data$Y, 0, 1)
```

But got nowhere. What can I do? As usual, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by `to no avail`?

Comment: Convert your columns to characters before doing the comparison.

Comment: Also note that colnames in `data` are in capital letters (X,Y), while inside your `ifelse` call are lower case (x,y).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out thanks to a comment that was somehow deleted:

```
ifelse(as.character(data$X) == as.character(data$Y), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use `ifelse`, just use the logical operator `!=`. Consider your dataframe is `df`:

```
> with(df, as.character(X)!=as.character(Y))*1
[1] 0 1 0 1
```

Comment: I prefer explicit conversion, rather than `*1`.